# How to configure network on Ubuntu 16 VM running on Openstack host?

Tags: cloud, openstack, snort, devstack

I am a junior in college, trying to do a simple project involving Devstack. Right now, I am trying to install Snort on a VM running through my Devstack host. It is going very slow, but I think I may eventually be able to do it, but I am worried about the networking of this VM and how it will intereact with other VM's.

My main question here is, **can I (or should I) install Snort on the Ubuntu machine that is running as my Devstack host?** Will it be effective, or is this how snort would be effectively deployed. I'm a just starting out with Devstack and do not know a ton about it, so any comments or advice would be helpful. So can I just install Snort and Devstack right along side of each other. Please let me know anything that you think, thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to install Snort in the same host as DevStack and not one of the VMs. I don't think you're going to face any issues. The important part (because DevStack messes a lot with the host machine) is that you maybe install Snort before running the _stack.sh_ script for DevStack.

Comment: I'm running my Devstack host on an Ubuntu 18 VirtualBox machine, with a bridged adapter.. When I ifconfig, I see two networks: "br-ex" which is 172.24.4.? and "enp0s3" which is 192.168.3.?. When I go to a browser to reach the dashboard, I type 192.168.3.165 ... Should I configure snort to listen on the 172 interface, or the 192 interface???